# I need a case statement like logic for my EF query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to somehow use this logic in my EF query, is this possile?

```
User
- salesCountUSA
- salesCountEurope
```

My method looks like

```
public List<User> GetUsers(bool isUSA, int salesCount)
{

 var users = from u in this.MyContext.Users
         where ????

}
```

In code I would do this:

```
int salesCount = isUsa ? salesCountUSA : salesCountEurope
```

How can I mimick this in EF?

Comment: Could you please post the definition of User, in order to see it's properties. Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you actually want here.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally construct the query due to deferred execution:

```
var query = MyContext.Users.AsQueryable();
if(isUSA)
    query = query.Where(user => user.salesCountUSA == salesCount)
else
    query = query.Where(user => user.salesCountEurope == salesCount)
```

Comment: I just did this:  ``` isUSA ? user.salesCountUSA == salesCount : user.salesCountEurope == salesCount)```   it seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LET statement

```
var users = from u in this.MyContext.Users
     let salesCount = u.isUsa ? u.salesCountUSA : u.salesCountEurope
     where salesCount > 0
```